# Python Floor Division Operator Break the Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

Could sombady explain me, why below code break the while loop, because of number is never below 0.

```
number = 50

while number > 0:
    number = number // 2
    print(number)

print("finish")
```

Comment: You must be able to see from the output that the last value of number is 0. At that point, the condition `number > 0` is false, and the loop ends. Zero is not greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your condition for the loop not to break. It is happening because python is rounding the result to 0.

```
number = 50

while number >= 0:
    number = number // 2
    print(number)

print("finish")
```

Comment: yes you are right but 0 is not lower than 0 so it must be infinite loop. Am I right.

Comment: @Codcz the moment the division gives 0(rounded) your loop stoops. Because you said run while the result is higher than 0, and 0 is not higher than 0, so it breaks.

Answer (score 0):

in line 3:

```py
while number > 0: ...
#     ^^^^^^^^^^
#        hear
```

## ******`You said it hear!!!`******